# Custom back button for NavigationController for every screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to subclass the UINavigationController class for modifying things like background image, navigation bar size, back button, tittle font and so on.
After a couple of hours and a lot of reading I have understand that I should not subclass the UINavigationController class...

I would like to have specific design and transfer that design to all screens that use my custom NavigationController...

SO far I haven't fount any elegant solution for this, most of the solutions are based on configuring something for showing in the next screen only (next view).

How can I achieve this? Maybe using categories?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many `UINavigationController` instances you'll have?

Comment: so why then bothering with complicated strategies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am showing code for custom leftbarbutton of `UINavigationcontroller`. You can add this code in each view controller and for both button( right and left)

```
    leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
    [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yourcutomeimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(youraction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton]autorelease];
```

//or

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton]autorelease];
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: What I am trying is to avoid configuration in each view controller. I would like to have it defined it only in one place and propagate the modifications everywhere.

Comment: Ok than make create one` UIViewControllerBase` class and use it anywhere you want. But at the bottom line you  can customize navigation button using above code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, thats what Im trying to do now. There is any way to use the default selector for the back button when declaring your own left button? I would like to avoid adding extra methods. Another question is why if I use a UIBarButtonItem I cannot set the tittle for the button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Nit is right, this is the way to customize the `UINavigationController`, but if you don't want to do it for every `UIViewController` you have, you can create a `UIViewControllerBase` class, which is a subclass of `UIViewController` and in `viewDidLoad` method, set all your buttons the way @Nit has described and then make every `UIViewController` you have to be a subclass of your `UIViewControllerBase` class.

Comment: Thats indeed a good idea. I was trying to have spaghetti code everywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom back button to uinavigationcontroller you should use navigationItem.backBarButtonItem and implement it in the class where you initialize the uinavigationcontroller.
Sample :-

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:youtarget action:@sel(your action)];  
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton; [backButton release];
```

Comment: What if the UINavigationController is initialized by the storyboard? (first view controller)?

Answer (score 0):

I have outlined my solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831482/171933

Basically, you create a category on UIViewController and call one single method in every `viewWillAppear` method of your view controllers.