# Why does my custom Navigation bar back button overlap/duplicated (Xcode 7.0)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I added the following to customize my back button in my navigation bar but the image just overlaps/duplicated:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyzJC.png

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //take out the label following the button
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    //set image for back button
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"backButtonImage.png"]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonImage.png"]];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

It's supposed to be an image of one black arrow facing to the left.

Before it worked fine but now it does this when I simulate it. Any insight and help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing that inside `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad:`? That replaces the back button everytime the view will appear, but it should be done once. I'm thinking you could simply hide the back bar button item (`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;` or `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`) and then add a customized one with an `IBAction` that performs `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506297/custom-back-button-in-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: @AlejandroIván Don't seem to work. Can you provide the full implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44);
back.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[back setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: back];
```

add a function:

```
-(void) back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: should I still include it in my viewWillAppear than viewDidLoad? Also should I keep the line of code that takes out the label following the button?

Comment: Both places are OK. Don't know about what you said, but this is just a '''back''' button. Just try to use it if is your requirement.

Comment: for example this: UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; Should I take it out?

Comment: also for action:@selector(back) I am getting an error: Undeclared selector 'back'

Comment: I actually replaced 'back' to 'leftBarButtonItem' and it cleared. But now when I click on the back button I am getting 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'.

Comment: Make sure what you want to do first, UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; seems this make no scene.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.00 alpha:1];
```

It should solve your problem.