# Want to simulate More Navigation Item behavior in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationitem

I have a view that can either be shown via another view or via the More tableview list of more controllers.

In the first case, I added a More button on the Navigation bar to take them back to the More view list, but what is the code that I put on the More button to take the user back to the More list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your backBarButtonItem check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526520/how-to-create-backbarbuttomitem-with-custom-view-for-a-uinavigationcontroller) question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking to see how to get back to the More list of TabBarController views. Is there a way to reference that list specifically so when the user clicks on the More button on the top of my view they are returned to the More list?