# set the back button from the pushViewController view

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, back-button

I have a viewController A, is it possible that I pre-set the back button of viewController B when it is pushed to.

```
Controller *B = [Controller viewControllerFromStoryboardWithProfile: profile editMode: NO];

    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];

    [B.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:B animated:YES];
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
```

source: [How to create backBarButtomItem with custom view for a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526520/how-to-create-backbarbuttomitem-with-custom-view-for-a-uinavigationcontroller/7184426#7184426)

Comment: Nice code, it works! just never thought that self.backBarButtonItem can "control" back button of the "next view"...